# Image's styles are ignored by iTextSharp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, razor, itext

image inside .cshtml file:

```
<img src="~/Content/images/imghead.png" style=" border:4px solid #ffffff; border-radius:10px; box-shadow: 2px 2px #f2f2f2; "/>
```

This is how it's supposed to be:

[image]

This is how it looks:

[image]

EDIT:
The row below produces the first image (rounded corners) upthere on the HTML output. On pdf output looks like second image.
Styles are not cared.

```
 <tr>
     <td align="center" style=" height:120px; ">
        <img src="https://abcstorage.blob.core.windows.net/Images/head.png" style="border:4px solid #ffffff; border-radius:10px; box-shadow: 2px 2px #f2f2f2; " />
     </td>
</tr>
```

This is the Render() Method:

```
using (var pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A3, HorizontalMargin, HorizontalMargin, 110, 30))
{
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, outputMemoryStream);
    pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
    pdfWriter.PageEvent = new PrintHeaderFooter();
    pdfDocument.Open();
    using (var htmlViewReader = new StringReader())
    {       
         XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(pdfWriter, pdfDocument, htmlViewReader);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not, how MVC works. You don't want to set any properties of your view elements in your controller. Use CSS.

Comment: itextSharp ignores styles

Comment: I don't understand relationship between your views and iTextSharp. Please give us more details.

Comment: iTextSharp doesn't handle every CSS property and `border-radius` is one that isn't supported. See [this for a list of supported properties](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm).

Comment: Nothing to suggest to make an image look circular?

Comment: Nothing simple. You'd need to first capture the border radius attribute, probably via a custom tag processor. Then upon rendering you'd need to apply a mask to the image, either via an image mask or a PDF clipping mask. Both aren't trivial.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how MVC work, the way you are doing it are more Asp .net Webform style.

Use css for this, or if you need dynamic change it use ViewBag such as (not tested):

Action

```
public ActionResult pdfOutput(string id, string pid)
{
    ViewBag.ImgHeadBorder=iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.BOX;
}
```

View

```
@if(ViewBag.ImgHeadBorder != null)
{
<img id="imgHead" src="~/Content/images/imghead.png" style="border:@ViewBag.ImgHeadBorder"/>
}
```